# Why does Google Map view over to the left?

Tags: google-maps

I put auto generating Google Maps in a directory I made for a client. (Demo: http://sudburyhomebuilders.com/directory/a-j-home-hardware/) When you click on "Find Us" it populates the map, puts the pin in the correct location, yet the view port is way over to the right. You have to zoom out and move of map over to see the location. Does anyone have any ideas on what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

After populate the map, pass coordinates of marker to map setCenter method
like this:

```
mapObject.setCenter(latLongObject);
```

Comment: But I'm embedding the map using iframe, not calling it from my JavaScript file.

Comment: Inside the iframe, in file that you implemented the map, create an event like "on add marker" triggering the centralization.
Find the correct event in API reference.